# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual

Tags: c#, mysql

I have execute the following query in mysql and found error.Can anyone identify the error in the mysql syntex.

```
INSERT INTO order values('2014-12-07','1','1',12,12,'1',12,'2014-12-07',-34)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`order` is a keyword, so you need to enclose it in quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `order` values('2014-12-07','1','1',12,12,'1',12,'2014-12-07',-34)
```

You should also specify the columns of the `order` table into which you are inserting the values to avoid ambiguities:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (col1, col2, ...) values('2014-12-07','1','1',12,12,'1',12,'2014-12-07',-34)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help and it finally worked :)